# What is a specifier-qualifier-list?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

GCC likes to tell me that I'm missing a specifier-qualifier-list in its error messages.

I know that this means I didn't put in a correct type of something.

But what exactly *is* a specifier-qualifier-list?

Edit:

Example C code that causes this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct { undefined_type *foo; } bar;
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
```

Gives these errors from GCC:

```
Lappy:code chpwn$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘undefined_type’
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example of a line of code that generates the error?

Comment: It is hard for those of us who have learned not to make whatever mistake it is you are making to guess what mistake you *are* making - so an illustration would help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a list of specifiers and qualifiers :-)  Specifiers are things like `void`, `char`, `struct Foo`, etc., and qualifiers are keywords like `const` and `volatile`.  See [this C grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#specifier-qualifier-list) for the definition.

In your case, `undefined_type` was not defined yet, so the parser saw it as an identifier, not a specifier-qualifier-list like it expected.  If you were to `typedef ... undefined_type;` before its occurrence, then `undefined_type` would become a specifier.

If you think in terms of parsing C with a context-free grammar, the way the compiler handles typedefs and such may be bothersome.  If I understand correctly, it games the parser generator by sneaking in symbol table operations so it can use context to parse the source code.